# How to set innerHTML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

How to apply for loop in javaScript and append all the li into paginationWrapper innerHTML. I tried below approach it does append only one by replacing the previous inner html

Here is my HTML

```
<nav aria-label="Page example">
    <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</nav>
```

```
const paginationWrapper = document.querySelector(".pagination");
let currentBatch = 1;
let pageButtonList = [1,2,3,4,5];
paginationWrapper.innerHTML= "";
for (let page = 0; page <= pageButtonList.length; page++){
    if(pageButtonList[page] === currentBatch){
        paginationWrapper.innerHTML = `<li className="page-item active"><button onclick="clickedButtonData(event)" value=${pageButtonList[page]} className="page-link">${pageButtonList[page]}</button></li>`;
    } else {
        paginationWrapper.innerHTML = `<li className="page-item"><button onclick="clickedButtonData(event)" value=${pageButtonList[page]}className="page-link">${pageButtonList[page]}</button></li>`;
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, feel free to mark it as the correct answer. Otherwise, we need some debug information (maybe some exceptions) from your dev tool console.

Comment: `innerHTML` is extremely unsuitable tool for the task. Take a look at [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep overwriting the same `innerHTML` on `paginationWrapper`. I think you want to use [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) or perhaps `paginationWrapper.innerHTML = paginationWrapper.innerHTML + '<new content>'`

Alternatively you could make the full list of child elements as a string and then use `.innerHTML`

```js
paginationWrapper.innerHTML = pageButtonList.map(page => {
  if(pageButtonList[page] === currentBatch) {
    return `<li className="page-item active"><button onclick="clickedButtonData(event)" value=${page} className="page-link">${page}</button></li>`;
  } else {
    return `<li className="page-item"><button onclick="clickedButtonData(event)" value=${page} className="page-link">${page}</button></li>`
  }
}).join('');
```

Comment: I think append is the best choice while creating new li and button

Comment: When i run this program and debug it does create inner HTML but its not visible

Comment: I'm thinking that might be something else in your code, perhaps a CSS style that's hiding it. Simple reproduction is

`document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(n => '<p>' + n + '</p>').join('')`

Running that on this page works if you give it a valid ID

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Just append your `<li>` elements using `+=` string concatination operator.

```
const paginationWrapper = document.querySelector(".pagination");
let currentBatch = 1;
let pageButtonList = [1,2,3,4,5];
paginationWrapper.innerHTML= "";
for (let page = 0 ; page <= pageButtonList.length ; page++){
    if(pageButtonList[page] === currentBatch){
        paginationWrapper.innerHTML += `<li className="page-item active"><button onclick="clickedButtonData(event)" value=${pageButtonList[page]} className="page-link">${pageButtonList[page]}</button></li>`;
    } else {
        paginationWrapper.innerHTML += `<li className="page-item"><button onclick="clickedButtonData(event)" value=${pageButtonList[page]}className="page-link">${pageButtonList[page]}</button></li>`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ops my bad by mistake while typing the i wrotewrong , but i think it still does not add all the ```li``` into innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of the fact that `innerHTML` removes all of the element's descendants and replaces them.

The simplest solution is just sth like `paginationWrapper.innerHTML += ...`

but.. I have to say that it's not the best way to add enw node elements to DOM.
Take a look at `wrapper.appendChild` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code does not append `innerHTML` because by definition `innerHTML` rewrites all the elements from the select tag by attribute with new data.

So simple workaround solution for this would be to concatenate all the li tags and then push it into the element using `innerHTML`

```
const paginationWrapper = document.querySelector(".pagination");
let currentBatch = 1;
let pageButtonList = [1,2,3,4,5];
let paginationtag = '';
paginationWrapper.innerHTML= "";
for (let page = 0; page <= pageButtonList.length; page++){
    if(pageButtonList[page] === currentBatch){
        paginationtag += `<li className="page-item active"><button onclick="clickedButtonData(event)" value=${pageButtonList[page]} className="page-link">${pageButtonList[page]}</button></li>`;
    } else {
        paginationtag += `<li className="page-item"><button onclick="clickedButtonData(event)" value=${pageButtonList[page]}className="page-link">${pageButtonList[page]}</button></li>`;
    }
}
paginationWrapper.innerHTML = paginationtag;
```